# Переполнение стека при десериализации объекта интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net, json

Я написал конвертер для открытого интерфейса, и внутреннего класса объекта.

При попытке десериализации объекта, по неизвестным мне причинам, происходит циклический вызов конвертера для данного объекта.

Конвертер:

```
internal class KodikMaterialConverter : JsonConverter<IMaterial>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IMaterial value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value, typeof(KodikMaterial));
    }

    public override IMaterial ReadJson
    (
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        IMaterial existingValue,
        bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer
    )
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize<KodikMaterial>(reader);
    }
}
```

Класс:

```
internal class KodikMaterial : IMaterial
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] public string Id { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")] public string Type { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("link")] public Uri Link { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")] public string Title { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("title_orig")] public string OriginalTitle { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("other_title")] public string OtherTitle { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("translation")] public ITranslation Translation { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("year")] public uint Year { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("last_season")] public uint LastSeason { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("last_episode")] public uint LastEpisode { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("episodes_count")] public uint EpisodesCount { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("kinopoisk_id")] public string KpId { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("imdb_id")] public string ImDbId { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("worldart_link")] public Uri WorldArtLink { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("quality")] public string Quality { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("camrip")] public bool IsCamRip { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("seasons")] public Dictionary<string, ISeason> Seasons { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("created_at")] public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("updated_at")] public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; internal set; }
    [JsonProperty("material_data")] public IMaterialData MaterialData { get; internal set; }
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(KodikMaterialConverter))]
public interface IMaterial
{
    string Id { get; }
    string Type { get; }
    Uri Link { get; }
    string Title { get; }
    string OriginalTitle { get; }
    string OtherTitle { get; }
    ITranslation Translation { get; }
    uint Year { get; }
    uint LastSeason { get; }
    uint LastEpisode { get; }
    uint EpisodesCount { get; }
    string KpId { get; }
    string ImDbId { get; }
    Uri WorldArtLink { get; }
    string Quality { get; }
    bool IsCamRip { get; }
    Dictionary<string, ISeason> Seasons { get; }
    DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; }
    DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; }
    IMaterialData MaterialData { get; }
}
```

Как избавиться от зацикливания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строка вызывает зацикливание:

```
return serializer.Deserialize<KodikMaterial>(reader);
```

Она опять создает инстанс `KodikMaterialConverter` и заново вызывает `ReadJson`.
Проверка на `StartObject` не спасет потому что это токен с которого начинается объект.

Вот как я советую сделать:

Создать чистую модель `KodikMaterialRaw` которая может распарсится без `KodikMaterialConverter` и потом передать её как аргумент конструктора `KodikMaterial` и внутри уже преобразовать как душе угодно.

Comment: Да... Странно конечно, я думал конвертер вызывается именно при попытке распаковки объекта, но видимо это не так.